# C++ std::string Parameter is <Bad Ptr>

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

I have a class with the following constructor:

```
CVideoAnnotation::CVideoAnnotation(std::string aPort, DWORD aBaudRate)
```

I create an instance of CVideoAnnotation as follows:

```
CVideoAnnotation cVideoAnnotation("COM3", CBR_9600);
```

'CBR_9600' is a macro that resolves to 9600.

Down in the constructor, aBaudRate is 9600 as expected. However, aPort does not get passed properly. When I hover the cursor over it, IntelliSense gives a value of `<Bad Ptr>`.

Does anybody have any thoughts on why the string does not pass properly?

Thanks,
Dave

As an update to my original question, I'm adding the assembly code for the constructor call and the population of locals once inside the constructor.

```
   CVideoAnnotation cVideoAnnotation("COM3", CBR_9600);
0041177D  push        2580h  
00411782  sub         esp,20h  
00411785  mov         ecx,esp  
00411787  mov         dword ptr [ebp-174h],esp  
0041178D  push        offset string "COM3" (4198C8h)  
00411792  call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (41131Bh)  
00411797  mov         dword ptr [ebp-17Ch],eax  
0041179D  lea         ecx,[ebp-11h]  
004117A0  call        dword ptr [__imp_CVideoAnnotation::CVideoAnnotation (41D4DCh)]  
004117A6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-180h],eax  
004117AC  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  





CVideoAnnotation::CVideoAnnotation(std::string aPort, DWORD aBaudRate)
{
100137F0  push        ebp  
100137F1  mov         ebp,esp  
100137F3  push        0FFFFFFFFh  
100137F5  push        offset __ehhandler$??0CVideoAnnotation@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@K@Z (1001DC82h)  
100137FA  mov         eax,dword ptr fs:[00000000h]  
10013800  push        eax  
10013801  sub         esp,164h  
10013807  push        ebx  
10013808  push        esi  
10013809  push        edi  
1001380A  push        ecx  
1001380B  lea         edi,[ebp-170h]  
10013811  mov         ecx,59h  
10013816  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
1001381B  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
1001381D  pop         ecx  
1001381E  mov         eax,dword ptr [___security_cookie (10026090h)]  
10013823  xor         eax,ebp  
10013825  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax  
10013828  push        eax  
10013829  lea         eax,[ebp-0Ch]  
1001382C  mov         dword ptr fs:[00000000h],eax  
10013832  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],ecx  
10013835  mov         dword ptr [ebp-84h],0  
1001383F  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0
```

Comment: I don't see any explicit pointers in your code, so it's possible that you're corrupting the stack somewhere.

Comment: I had wondered about that; however, the very first thing that happens in _tmain() is the CVideoAnnotation construction shown in my original post. (_tmain() is the entry point for a Windows console application with a precompiled header.) Before this, stdafx.h, iostream, conio.h, and VideoAnnotation.h are included. In turn, VideoAnnotation.h does this:
#pragma once
#include <string>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#ifdef EXPORTING_DLL
#define DECL_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECL_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are implementing CVideoAnnotation in a separate DLL then you are having a well know issue of crossing DLL boundaries when using STL containers. To verify that this is the case create a new constructor taking a const char* instead of std::string and try..

Another thing, instead of std::string prefer to use const std::string&

Comment: I am indeed crossing a DLL boundary. I will try your suggestion for the purposes of determining if this is the problem. But I'll still ask... Is there a workaround that doesn't involve changing the constructor signature? I do not have ownership of that constructor and am not at liberty to change it (other than in a local experiment).

Comment: Passing the C-string worked. I am apparently hitting this STL DLL boundary issue. I'm starting to google around to learn about this issue and see if there's a workaround that would allow me to leave the constructor signature unchanged...

Comment: Try this link Dave: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172396/en-us/ I faced this exact problem several years ago using VC++ 6.0 ..  It was documented from MSDN since then and I was assumed it would had been fixed....  If I am not wrong when I started using stlport instead of Plaunger's STL (default VS ) the problem disapeared

Comment: The DLL issue has been fixed ages ago. Furthermore, the default runtime library option has always been to link the CRT (including `std::string`) as a DLL, which meant that even in VC6 the default just worked.

Answer (score 2):

Passing `string` to and from DLLs should work just fine.  As noted above using STL containers in this way can be problematic but `string` is fine.

Do you have any evidence beyond Intellisense that the string is messed up?  In Release builds Intelliesnse can be sketchy.  Try adding `cout << aPort << endl;` into that constructor to make sure.

If it really is incorrect I would just debug from the caller into the constructor call - see where the `string` is pushed as a parameter, and see where on the stack it's picked up from for use inside the constructor.  Something must be out of sync here, assuming both DLL and app use the same version of the C++ runtimes, and you should be able to tell why by inspecting the assembler code.

Comment: Yes, the string really is bad (cout results in an access violation). I have added assmebly to my original post and am trying to make sense of it now.

Answer (score 0):

"COM3" is not a std::string it is a const char *,  try creating a std::string to pass in.

Comment: `std::string` has a constructor that takes a `const char *`.

Comment: Passing a std::string yields the same result. In any case, std::string has a const char * converting constructor; calling it in the manner I have is standard-compliant.

Comment: As casablanca mentioned above  cVideoAnnotation("COM3", CBR_9600) is absolutely correct syntactically since it creates an implicit string object. Of course if the constructor was expecting a string& the code would not complile (in this case we have to use a const string& instead)

Comment: as JohnP points out in his answer above while it may be standards compliant it doesn't always work in non standard areas of the language such as when dealing with DLLs.  I have had good luck with the making it a string before passing it to the dll before though it has been a while and things change.

Answer (score 0):

I too was fighting what looked like bad byte alignment resulting in .  Based on the suggestions here that crossing library boundaries can be problematic, I suspected (even though I am using a static library instead of DLL) that I might be dealing with the same sort of problem.  I was instantiating a class in one library whose code was in another.  When I moved the instantiation into the library where its code was the problem went away.  I don't understand why this worked but at least I can now move forward.